# Disable past dates in datepicker js

Tags: javascript, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I want to disable all the dates in calendar which is lesser than today.
I tried adding     $("#ctl00_MainContent_tbxLetterDate").datepicker({ minDate: +0 }); 
But it dosent work, Here is my code..

```
$("#ctl00_MainContent_tbxLetterDate").datepicker({ changeYear: true, dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy', showOn: 'none', showButtonPanel: true });
    $("#ctl00_MainContent_tbxLetterDate").attr('readOnly', 'true');
    $("#ctl00_MainContent_tbxLetterDate").datepicker({ minDate: +0 }); 
    $("#ctl00_MainContent_imgLetterDate").live("click", function () {
        $("#ctl00_MainContent_tbxLetterDate").datepicker('show'); return false;
    });
```

Comment: have you tried like `$( "#ctl00_MainContent_tbxLetterDat" ).datepicker({ minDate: -20, maxDate: "+1M +10D" });`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it like this, with string value

```
 minDate:'0d'

$("#ctl00_MainContent_tbxLetterDate").datepicker({ changeYear: true, dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy', showOn: 'none', showButtonPanel: true,  minDate:'0d' });
```

And check it after

```
alert( $("#ctl00_MainContent_tbxLetterDate").datepicker( "option", "minDate" ));
```